# how to count $dataProvider items

Tags: yii

how can i count data that will retrieved by $dataProvider ?
i've tried to use this code,

```
       $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Model');
       $dataProvider->totalItemCount;
```

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 43):

In yii2

For total count use

`$dataProvider->getTotalCount()`

For page count then

`$dataProvider->getCount()`

Refrence page
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider.html#getTotalCount()-detail

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to first fill the dataprovider with data then get the count:

```
 $dataProvider->getData();
 var_dump($dataProvider->totalItemCount);
```

or use the function to retrieve directly:

```
 var_dump($dataProvider->getTotalItemCount());
```

Comment: Do bear in mind that this will be number of records restricted by the pagesize as applicable.

Comment: this is independent from page size!

Comment: Figured you were using count on the data returned from getData  from the first line , you don't need to do that before being able to calculate the count. FYI getData only returns the records from the current page segment.

Comment: yes `getData()` will get data according to page size,but property `totalItemCount` is empty before that.you either have to use the **get function** , or call `getData()`, otherwise why would some one ask a question about this??

Comment: you are either confused or not able to express your point clearly. Either way you DON'T need to use getData() to retrieve count values from $dataProvider->totalItemCount